# How can I override PostgreSQL's gen_random_uuid() in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-7, pgcrypto

I want to prepend a string to the uuid generated by PostgreSQL's gen_random_uuid() to use as the uuid for one of my models (it won't be the primary key).

Think like Stripe's price and customer ids - `"price_xxxx..."` and `"cus_xxxx..."`

Currently I'm using gen_random_uuid() like so:

```
t.uuid "uuid", default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, null: false
```

Is it possible to do something like,

```
t.uuid "uuid", default: -> { "xxx" + "gen_random_uuid()" }, null: false
```

?

Comment: You can't use rails to *override* a Postgres function. But you could either use a different postgres function, or stop relying on a postgres function at all (i.e. set the default value at the rails application level, not at a database level).

Comment: Regarding your suggestion, I haven't tried it, but does this work? `default: -> { "'xxx' + gen_random_uuid()" }`

Comment: @TomLord thanks, is there any significant disadvantage to just setting it at the Rails application level?

Comment: @TomLord, I tried to set it that way in a migration and got `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
... "xxx_" + "gen_random_uuid()" }`

Comment: Note my use of double and single brackets. I'm not sure exactly what you wrote to get that error, but it's likely caused by some mis-match.

Comment: In addition, I'm **not sure** whether the UUID you're trying to set would be considered [a valid UUID field in postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html). If it doesn't work, you may need to fall back on a regular text field for that format.

Comment: *"is there any significant disadvantage to just setting it at the Rails application level?"* -- Probably a tiny performance loss (but likely insignificant). The only *potential* issue I'd be worried about is if there's a risk of inconsistency, e.g. if there are multiple applications writing to this database.

Comment: @TomLord Okay, thanks. I think I may just use the value returned by `gen_random_uuid()` and simply differentiate between different resources in the URL. Ie instead of `xxx_UUID`, just use example.com/xxx/UUID.

Answer (score 1):

Solving it at the model level could be an option

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :uuid, default: -> { "xxx_#{SecureRandom.uuid}" }
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought of this, I just thought performance would be better if I did at the database level. I don't know if the gains are trivial/nonexistent, though. How would this solution work in practice? Would the uuid be defined as this default upon instantiation of the record, or updated after instantiation?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Postgres-specific solution, try this:

```
t.uuid 'uuid', default: -> { "'xxx' || gen_random_uuid()" }, null: false
```

(Postgres does string concatenation via ||, and recognises text in "ticks" (apostrophes) as being strings.)

Comment: Oh that's amazing, thank you!